# On DELETE CASCADE not working in snowflake

Tags: ddl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cascade

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE category(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT CATEGORY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE product(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT PRODUCT_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    id_category INTEGER REFERENCES category(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

When I `DELETE FROM category`, the products do not get deleted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any workarounds found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thing is Snowflake doesn't really service constraints other than not null. It will have them (as in store somewhere) but not really enforce - which means your cascade won't work.

reference:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constraints-overview.html

Comment: This is a real issue for me, moving away from a MySQL database to Snowflake. I take it that this is just something that isn't supported OR can it do it but isn't enabled by default?